# UITableView Animations

Tags: iphone, animation, uitableview

I am attempting to create a animated cell when it is selected. Everything seems to be working really odd. If I send the ButtonView to the Self.contentView of the UITableView Cell it works like it is supposed to and adds the cell in desired row but I loose button functionality at index row. If I send the buttonview to just self "UITableViewCell" I have button index row but it adds the button view in about every 10 rows.

Now the animation itself looks great when it works right. The issue is I am using a method to toggle the path selected  so I can grow the cell height to twice the size when selected and stay selected until another cell is selected.

Really I have no idea where to go from here I was hoping maybe someone could help me find my mistake or have delt with something similar.

Thanks I appreciate any insight!

```
- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Return whether the cell at the specified index path is selected or not
NSNumber *selectedIndex = [selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
return selectedIndex == nil ? FALSE : [selectedIndex boolValue];
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    
*)indexPath {




[sounds PlayButtonClick:nil];
// Deselect cell ..?
//[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

// Toggle 'selected' state

BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];

// Store cell 'selected' state keyed on indexPath
NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
[selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath]; 

// This is where magic happens...
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
[sounds PlaySlide:nil];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {
// If our cell is selected, return double height

if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {


    return 70 *2;
}

return 70;
}
```

And from my CellClass

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if (self == [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;




}

return self;
}



- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

if (selected == YES) {

    NSLog(@"is selected");
   [self showButtonView:!selected];
 [self applyDropShadow:!selected];
   // TweettextLabel.hidden = YES;
   // Tweettext.hidden = NO;

}
if (selected == NO){
  [self removeButtonView:!selected];
 [self removeDropShadow:!selected];
    //TweettextLabel.hidden = NO;
    //Tweettext.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"is NOT selected");
}

}




-(void)showButtonView:(int)view{



CGRect viewFrame = [ButtonView frame];
viewFrame.origin.y = 0; 
self.ButtonView.frame = viewFrame;  
[self.contentView insertSubview:self.ButtonView belowSubview:self.cellView];      
[self addSubview:self.contentView];


[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
CGRect viewFrame1 = [ButtonView frame];
viewFrame1.origin.y = 70;
ButtonView.frame = viewFrame1; 
[UIView commitAnimations];    

}

-(void)removeButtonView:(int)view{

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
CGRect viewFrame1 = [self.ButtonView frame];
viewFrame1.origin.y = 0;
self.ButtonView.frame = viewFrame1; 
[UIView commitAnimations];    

// timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self     
selector:@selector(removeLastViewFromSuper) userInfo:Nil repeats:NO]; 

}



-(void)applyDropShadow:(int)shadow{

self.contentView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.8f, -4.0f);
self.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
self.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;     
}

-(void)removeDropShadow:(int)shadow{
self.contentView.layer.shadowColor =  [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
self.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
self.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
self.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0; 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the buttonView to the cell's `contentView` when you create it. Show and hide it by setting the `hidden` or `alpha` property. Now the problem of not getting the button to work should go away.

Also, your dictionary with the selected indexes seems a bit overdone if you only have one cell that is selected. Just create a property "selected" of type `NSIndexPath` in the controller.

Finally, your selected cell repeating when you scroll is due to the re-queuing mechanism of `UITableView`. Make sure that you set the correct `hidden` property for the button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` each time. This way, when a cell is recycled that has a non-hidden button, it will hide it if the index path is not the selected one.